# Posting Multiple forms in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML page having multiple forms and a button outside the forms as below:-

```
<html>    
<body>

<div class="error" style="display:none;">
    <span></span>            
</div>
<form id="form1" name="form1"> 
Field 1: <input name="field1" id="field1" type="text" class="required">
</form>
<form id="form2" name="form2"> 
Field 2: <input name="field2" id="field2" type="text" class="required">
</form>

<div>
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Validate">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the button the jQuery validation works for Form1 and if it passes the jQuery validation for Form2 works. IF that is also succesfull, I need to submit the forms to back end. The problem here is I can submit ony 1 form at a time. 
But I need to sent the form values in both Form1 and Form2 once both the forms passes the jQuery validation. How can I achieve this? I have found that we can create a new form in javascript and add all the form elements to the new form and submit that form. But I am not sure how much feasible is this solution since each form contains a minimum of 100 form fields and it needs to work in both IE and FF.

Comment: Building a single form (or combining the two forms on the page) is the thing to do. You *could* alternatively target two hidden `<iframe>` elements and post the forms separately, but then you'd have to do some fancy work to figure out when both are done, report errors, etc.

Comment: Where do you want to submit these forms to

Comment: "Building a single form (or combining the two forms on the page) is the thing to do." Can this be acheived in jQuery that works in IE and FF?

Comment: @Akhil Sekharan -  I want to submit the forms will all form fields back to my server.

Comment: Can you show your javascript ?

Comment: there is a very simple and non practical way , after completion of the two forms , store all the values in a third hidden form and actualy submit only the third one , btw  , can you explain the scenario where you need two forms , because in most cases we dont

Comment: @Akhil Sekharan - Yes it is posting to the same url.

Comment: @nicolast - http://jsfiddle.net/ajithmanmu/YQSj8/

Comment: And your server side lang is

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid  - The reason for using  multiple forms was because I want to use jQuery.valid method to each form for validation. There are many form fields in the current form and it will crash IE when calling the jQuery valid method. So as a workaround I splitted the form into multiple smaller forms and then call the validation for each.

Comment: @Akhil Sekharan - ColdFusion

Answer (score 0):

After performing your Javascript validation, you can simply grab the data from each of the forms using serialize and submit it using ajax or post.

Something like this should work:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: $("#form1,#form2").serialize(),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are submitting will be just the last hidden form. Using jquery you can put all your values into the hidden form as json string. You can use DeserializeJSON method to get it in your server side script.

Hope this helps:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1"> 
    Field 1: <input name="field1" id="field1" type="text" class="required">
</form> 
<form id="form2" name="form2"> 
    Field 2: <input name="field2" id="field2" type="text" class="required">
</form>
<form id="form3" name="form3"> 
    Field 3: <input name="field3" id="field3" type="text" class="required">
</form>
..........//After all your forms, just make a hidden form
<form id="hiddenForm" action="your required url">
    <input name="finalField" id="finalField" type="text" style="display:none;" class="required">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit(){
        var data = new Object();
        $('form').each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('id') != 'hiddenForm')
                data[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).serialize();
        });
        $('#finalField').val(JSON.stringify(data));
        $('#hiddenForm').submit();
    }
</script>
```